# Multidimensional Array to initialize ncurses items

Tags: c

Is there a way to implement a ncurses screen with items, which are initialized by a multidimensional array?

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <menu.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define CTRLD   4

char *choices[] = {
                        "Choice 1",
                        "Choice 2",
                        "Choice 3",
                        "Choice 4",
                        "Exit",
                  };

int main()
{   ITEM **my_items;
    int c;              
    MENU *my_menu;
    int n_choices, i;
    ITEM *cur_item;
    
    
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    
    n_choices = ARRAY_SIZE(choices);
    my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));
    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i)
            my_items[i] = new_item(choices[i], choices[i]);
    my_items[n_choices] = (ITEM *)NULL;
    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);
    mvprintw(LINES - 2, 0, "F1 to Exit");
    post_menu(my_menu);
    refresh();

    while((c = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
    {   switch(c)
        {   case KEY_DOWN:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
                break;
        }
    }   

    free_item(my_items[0]);
    free_item(my_items[1]);
    free_menu(my_menu);
    endwin();
}
```

In this code from the menu library the char array "choices" is used to initialize the items.
Is there a way to implement the same thing with a multidimensional array like:

```
char *choices[][5] = {
    "Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3", "Choice 4", "Choice 5",
    "Choice 6", "Choice 7", "Choice 8", "Choice 9", "Choice 10",
    "Choice 11", "Choice 12", "Choice 13", "Choice 14", "Choice 15",
    "Choice 16", "Exit",
};
```

EDIT:

I tried to iterate through two nested for-loops but this causes a segfault:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <menu.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define CTRLD 4

char *choices[][5] = {
    "Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3", "Choice 4", "Choice 5",
    "Choice 6", "Choice 7", "Choice 8", "Choice 9", "Choice 10",
    "Choice 11", "Choice 12", "Choice 13", "Choice 14", "Choice 15",
    "Choice 16", "Exit",
};

// test **t = (test **)malloc(20 * sizeof(test *));
// for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
//     t[i] = (test *)malloc(20 * sizeof(test));

int main()
{
    int rows = sizeof(choices) / sizeof(choices[0]); // returns rows
    int col = sizeof(choices[0]) / sizeof(int);      // returns col

    ITEM **my_items;
    MENU *my_menu;
    int n_choices, i, j;
    ITEM *cur_item;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    WINDOW *mainWindow = newwin(0, 0, 0, 0);

    n_choices = rows * col;
    my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));
    int k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            my_items[k] = new_item(choices[i][j], "");
            k++;
        }
    }
    my_items[n_choices] = (ITEM *)NULL;

    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);
    mvprintw(LINES - 2, 0, "F1 to Exit");
    post_menu(my_menu);
    refresh();

    int c;
    while ((c = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case KEY_DOWN:
            menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
            break;
        case KEY_UP:
            menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
            break;
        }
    }

    free_item(my_items[0]);
    free_item(my_items[1]);
    free_menu(my_menu);
    endwin();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: A Segfault is caused. I posted the code i tried.

Comment: Please post whatever info you have on the segfault (for example, where it occurred).